# Potentiometer for TL081

Tags: operational-amplifier, potentiometer

What kind of potentiometer (resistance) would be suitable to connect to the Offset pins on the TL081 Op amp, when used with +/-15V? And if I choose to omit the pot altogether, roughly speaking, how much would the output be offset by?

Comment: "work well with the TL081": well, I find that a thing slice of salami works well with my toast when I marvel at my Opamps ;) so, please explain what you're trying to build, where you need that potentiometer / which purpose it serves. we can't guess what you want to build.

Comment: also, don't use the TL081. It only exists for historical reasons. It's literally at least 41 years old at this point. There's many opamps that are better in *every* aspect than the TL081.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, The op amp is being used to generate a +/-10v signal, with the input coming from a DAC. The op amp is to be configured as a differential amplifier. I'm not sure what resistance range (10kohm seems typical) the potentiometer needs to be.

Comment: Can you suggest a better Op amp?

Comment: your comment still doesn't explain in which circuit you're using the potentiometer, so please edit your question and draw a schematic.

Answer (score 2):

Use a 100K pot for offset null. Usually the range is something like double the maximum offset in either direction.

I don't know why they don't tell you that on the TI datasheet (edit- see below). Here's an image from the 2nd source (ST) datasheet:

[image]

You should not use the offset null circuit to create a non-zero offset, as that will compromise the temperature drift.

Edit: Okay, this circuit is shown in [this](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl082b.pdf) TI datasheet (also 100K pot but with an added small resistor in series with the wiper).

[image]

I don't see a reference to that configuration elsewhere in the datasheet, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Is the 1.5k resistor really necessary?

Comment: I don't think so. The pot should never be right over at one end or the other.

Comment: I guess it's there to protect against shorts. Is the pot defaulted to 0ohms when delivered?

Comment: Varies-- sometimes pots are shipped set to the middle, which is ideal from a production point of view, but sometimes random.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for a more modern op amp?

Comment: There are a lot of possibilities, depending on what your requirements are. You have mentioned one- +/-15V operation, and presumably you want Vos to be less than 6mV or you wouldn't be asking about adjusting it. ADA4610-1 is pretty good for an inexpensive JFET-input op-amp. If you are primarily interested in DC characteristics there are much better choices. If you want something that costs pennies for a high volume design the TL08x is still viable.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why the ADA4610-1 doesn't have offset null pins?

Comment: Most modern op-amps don't have offset null pins. If low offset is important to you, you buy an op-amp that has low Vos (and low TCVos, and drift). It's possible to get microvolts of offset out of the box and drift of +/-50nV/°C.

Comment: Ahhh ok. I would assume in a closed loop application, some offset shouldn't be too much of a problem anyway. Is that right?

Comment: Depends entirely on the application. If you have a precision DC application with low level signals (eg. thermocouple signals or a shunt measuring current) then offset can be really important.

Comment: The application in question involves a motor in closed loop control (PID). I would think a bit of offset shouldn't be too much of a problem.

Comment: If your feedback signal is 5V for 20,000 RPM full scale (speed control) and you have 10mV of offset, that's 40 RPM of error that the integral term won't correct. So at 400 RPM you have a 10% error. Etc.

Comment: As an encoder is being used to measure speed, surely the integral term would still be able to correct for error.

Comment: Just to clarify, the op amp output is being used to drive an inverter, not to determine speed/position, etc.